edit_protection() got an unexpected keyword argument
branch.edit_protection(
                    enforce_admins=desired_protection_settings["enforce_admins"],
                    required_linear_history=desired_protection_settings["required_linear_history"],
                    # required_conversation_resolution=desired_protection_settings["required_conversation_resolution"],  # Not supported in this version
                    lock_branch=desired_protection_settings["lock_branch"],
                    allow_fork_syncing=desired_protection_settings["allow_fork_syncing"],
                    users_bypass_pull_request_allowances=desired_protection_settings["users_bypass_pull_request_allowances"],
                    teams_bypass_pull_request_allowances=desired_protection_settings["teams_bypass_pull_request_allowances"],
                    apps_bypass_pull_request_allowances=desired_protection_settings["apps_bypass_pull_request_allowances"],
                    block_creations=desired_protection_settings["block_creations"],
                    require_last_push_approval=desired_protection_settings["require_last_push_approval"]
                )



I am having issues with parameters in edit_protection. I started writing a script that needs to update some protection parameters but it seems like I'm constantly getting errors that some fields that should be allowed(checked the documentation for edit_protection) like required_conversation_resolution, required_linear_history, allow_deletions.
Does anyone have a clue why?
If reviewed documentation, rewrote the code several times, debugged but no luck. Maybe I'm missing something.

You need to include the full error traceback message.  Looking at the source code for edit_protection(), I don't see any way that the claimed errors could occur.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

if you want us to check the documentation for edit_protection then add link for this documentation. And put it in question, not in comments.

maybe you should check source code instead of documentation. Maybe they have different name in code. You may also try to use function help() - help( branch.edit_protection ) - to see if code has docstrings with documentation.
